# Произношение безударных гласных после буквы Й

Tags: орфоэпия

Как необходимо произносить предударные гласные в словах, которые начинаются на **Й**?

Например, [*Йо*]шкар- Ола, [*Йа*]шкар - Ола или [*Йи*]шкар - Ола? [*Йо*]тированный, [*Йа*]тированный или [*Йи*]тированный,и т.д.

А так же, как произносятся гласные после **й** в таких словах как ма**йо**нез, ма**йо**ран, ма**йо**рат, р**ай**онирование? Со звукосочетанием [йа],[йо] или [йи]?